# Running gscam simultaneously on multiple laptops having a common ROSmaster

Tags: gscam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have three laptops of which one will act as the master. They are all connected to the same network. When I try to run gscam on one slave and access it from the master the setup works perfectly. But when I run gscam on the second slave, the first slave's terminal that was running gscam receives a shutdown request citing the reason "new node registered with same name" and stops working. The second slave starts working. But I want them both to run simultaneously.

I tried changing the node name by changing the executable name in the CMakeLists.txt file. Even then the problem persists.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55307/running-gscam-simultaneously-on-multiple-laptops-having-a-common-rosmaster/) by [Bala](https://answers.ros.org/users/4104/bala/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-02-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Don't change the name of the executable, change the node name by passing: `__name:=new_name`

You can also produce a roslaunch file the automatically assigns anonymous node names.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2